# xcodebuild -exportArchive: ipa file contains no Info.plist

Tags: ios, xcodebuild

i'm currently trying to export my .xarchive file using "xcodebuild -exportArchive -archivPath pathTo.xarchive -exportOptionsList pathTo.plist -exportPath targetPath".

The export itself is working, however inside my generated IPA file i'm missing the Info.plist file.

Did anyone else encounter this problem or does know why the Info.plist is missing?

Comment: Are you sure that the plist path is correct?

Comment: @SaintThread Hi, yea the path is correct. I've tested to input an invalid .plist path. xcodebuild throws errors if the path is not correct. Thanks anyway